# Extracting multiple text with regex and matching the existence as a condition

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract elements using a regex, while needing to also distinguish which lines have "-External" at the end.  The naming structure I am working with is:

```
<ServerName>: <Country>-<CountryCode>
or 
<ServerName>: <Country>-<CountryCode>-External
```

For example:

```
test1 = 'Neo1: Brussels-BRU-External'
test2 = 'Neo1: Brussels-BRU'

match = re.search(r'(?<=: ).+', test1)

print match.group(0)
```

This gives me "Brussels-BRU".  I am trying to extract "Brussels" and "BRU" separately, while not caring about anything to the left of the `:`.

After, I need to know when a line has "-External".  Is there a way I can treat the existence of "-External" as `True` and without as `None`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that regexs are not needed here, and that a simple split or 2 can get you what are after.  Here is a way to `split()` the line into pieces from which you can then select what you are interested in:

#### Code:

```
def split_it(a_string):
    on_colon = a_string.split(':')
    return on_colon[0], on_colon[1].strip().split('-')
```

#### Test Code:

```
tests = (
    'Neo1: Brussels-BRU-External',
    'Neo1: Brussels-BRU',
)

for test in tests:
    print(split_it(test))
```

#### Results:

```
('Neo1', ['Brussels', 'BRU', 'External'])
('Neo1', ['Brussels', 'BRU'])
```

#### Analysis:

The length of the list can be used to determine if the additional field `'External'` is present.